# What is x-wmapp2 and x-wmapp1?

Tags: c#, javascript, cordova, windows-phone-7.1

I am getting `x-wmapp2:/app/www/index.html` as output when I try to `console.log(windows.location.href);` in my Windows Phone PhoneGap app when I try to run in emulator.  When I try to run actual device, it gives `x-wmapp1:/app/www/index.html`. What is x-wmapp2 and x-wmapp1? What is the difference between them? I also find there exists x-wmapp0 also. Could someone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be the `Scheme` of the `WebBrowser` element whenever one is opening locally-stored web pages.

Actually, it starts from `x-wmapp0` and is incremented for every new instance of `WebBrowser`. Whenever the app is started anew or tombstoned and restarted, the count goes back to zero.

Of course, these is my personal experience. Only a chap from the IE team at MS could say for certain.