# Cordova wp8 app not initializing in Windows Phone 8/8.1 Emulator

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-cordova, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am developing a Cordova app that is working fine in both Android and iOS, but there is a problem when running both in Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1 emulators (I am targeting the `wp8` cordova platform).

The app loads to the home page, but in the output window I see the this messages:

```
CordovaBrowser_LoadCompleted
Apache Cordova native platform version 3.8.2 is starting
Error::Plugin not allowed in config.xml. StatusBar
Error::Plugin not allowed in config.xml. Device
Error::Plugin not allowed in config.xml. NetworkStatus
CordovaBrowser_LoadCompleted
Apache Cordova native platform version 3.8.2 is starting
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady
Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady
```

Every time I interact with the app (scroll, tap on links/buttons, ...), nothing happens in the emulator, and in the output window the following lines appears again:

```
CordovaBrowser_LoadCompleted
Apache Cordova native platform version 3.8.2 is starting
```

I am using the emulator because for now I do not have a real device.

**UPDATE**

After running another time `cordova prepare wp8`, the errors regarding plugins, deviceready and "Channel not fired" disappeared; however, the app is still not working properly, I still get the CordovaBrowser_LoadCompleted and "Apache  Cordova native..." messages every time I try to use the app.

Comment: Which `cordova` platform are you targeting for windows phone? `wp8` or `windows` ?

Comment: @Beat I am targeting `wp8`

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373565/windows-phone-8-ionic-app-navigation-issuehybrid-application

Comment: @SantoshShinde thanks, I read the question and its answers, but I don't understand how it can be useful for my problem; could you please clarify?

Comment: please let me know after click your app get closed or not

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to emulate Windows Phone 8.1, you have to use the windows platform in Cordova/PhoneGap rather than the wp8 platform.

```
cordova platform rm wp8
cordova platform add windows
```

More information are available [here](http://akvelon.com/apache-cordova-adds-windows-8-1-and-windows-phone-8-1-universal-apps-support/) and [here](http://akvelon.com/apache-cordova-adds-windows-8-1-and-windows-phone-8-1-universal-apps-support/).

Hope this will help you !

Comment: Thank you Santosh; I downloaded the correct emulator for WP8 but the problem persists.

Comment: please try with platform windows

Comment: using platform `windows`it compiles and launch, but it doesn't work due to the "Unable to add dynamic content" error; whilst there is a [workaround](https://github.com/MsopenTech/winstore-jscompat), I do not have time to implement it, and the app itself must target WP8.