# Issue with Ionic pull to refresh and other transitions on Windows Phone

Tags: ionic-framework

I know this might be a bit off topic was windows isn't supported by Ionic, but I was wondering if anyone had had any luck fixing some of the CSS oddities I am facing when building my app on a Windows 10 Phone.

The first issue is with pull to refresh. It still seems to function correctly, but the movement of the element being dragged down seems quite jumpy and in certain cases it won't move at all until the user releases their finger from the screen at which point it will jump down and refresh.

The second issue is with footer elements not moving up when the keyboard is showing.

The final issue is with side menus not closing properly. My app currently uses a side menu on both sides and it appears that when I close either side menu a slight portion of the right side menu displays in the header momentarily.

One other thing to note is that when I build the app for local machine (using x86 architecture) all the transitions seem to work fine.

If anyone has any suggestions or would be able to help that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please check to here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373565/windows-phone-8-ionic-app-navigation-issuehybrid-application

Comment: Hi Santosh, not really related to my question. But thanks for the info!